# Backspace does not delete dashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a field that adds dashes to a number so that it takes the form of a telephone number.  It adds the dashes, but if the user tries to backspace their way back to the beginning it does not allow the user to delete the dash.  Well, it deletes it but then the dash re-populates.

The JavaScript that allows only numbers with exceptions that I'm currently using:

```
function forceNumber(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 58) && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 188 && keyCode != 189) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The js that creates the dashes:

```
function addDashes(n){
    n = n.replace(/,/g, "");
    var s=n.split('.')[1];
    (s) ? s="."+s : s="";
    n=n.split('.')[0];
    if(n.length == 3 || n.length == 7 || n.length == 13){
        s="-"
    }
    return n+s;
}
```

And the PHP/HTML call (I'm not sure if the right-align may be the cause):

```
<p id="phone_number">
    <label for="phone_number"><?php _e('Phone Number','mydomain') ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="input" size="25" style="text-align:right" onkeypress="return forceNumber(event);" onkeyup="this.value=addDashes(this.value);"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change in your html I changed this line to add the event information:

```
<input ... onkeyup="this.value=addDashes(this.value, event);"/>
```

In the addDashes function I changed the signature to take the event and added an if to handle the backspace

```
function addDashes(n, ev){
    // ... 
}
```

However I noticed a more fundamental problem with your method.  If somebody inserts a character it'll break the logic.  So if the text is 123-45, and I paste the number 6 between 2 & 3, the result will be 1263-45.

Here's a different approach to addDashes that just checks the whole string each time.

```
function addDashes(n, ev){
    n = n.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    if (n.length > 3) {
        n = insert(n, 3, '-');
        if (n.length > 7) {
            n = insert(n, 7, '-');
            if (n.length > 13) {
               n = insert(n, 13, '-');   
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}

function insert(s1, index, s2) {
   return s1.substring(0, index) + s2 + s1.substring(index);
}
```

Another variation of addDashes that avoids the conditionals in favor of an unwieldy regex.

```
function addDashes(n, ev){
     n = n.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")
         .replace(/(\d{3}(?=\d))((\d{3}(?=\d))|(\d{0,3}$))((\d{4}(?=\d))|(\d{0,4}$))/, 
         function(m, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) {
             return (($1) ? $1 + '-' : m) + 
                 (($3) ? $3 + '-' : $4) +
                 (($6) ? $6 + '-' : $7);
         });
    return n;
}
```

You can also adjust the second method to do different formatting without having to worry about string lengths.  For example you can change the replace function to return in the format (ddd) ddd-dddd

```
             return (($1) ? '(' + $1 + ') ' : m) + 
                 (($3) ? $3 + '-' : $4) +
                 (($6) ? $6 + '-' : $7);
```

Comment: With your last/regex block, as you type you get the following:
 `123-123`, `1231-231`, `123-1231-2`, `123-1231-23`, `123-1231-234`. The regex could be changed to `/(\d{3}(?=\d))((\d{3}(?=\d))|(\d{0,3}$))((\d{4}(?=\d))|(\d{0,4}$))/` and the last concatenation of the `return` could be changed to `(($6) ? $6 : $7)` to make this work properly.

Comment: You were right on that the problem was I was doing (\d{4}(?=\d))|(\d{0,3}$)), instead of \d{0,4}.  Originally I had it adding the dashes right after they 4th key press, instead of waiting for the fifth.  I don't know why the return needs to be changed.  Also I never even caught that it was for phone numbers.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked!  Thanks!  I didn't have time to try all of these methods this afternoon but after the first method still led to the dash reappearing I gave your method a shot and it worked wonderfully.  The dash is not coming back!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n.length == 3 || n.length == 7 || n.length == 13){
    s="-"
}
```

When you backspace the dash, the length is 3 again, so the dash gets added. You are going to have to check if the last key the user pressed is backspace, like

```
var lastKeyIsBackspace;
if(!lastKeyIsBackspace && (n.length == 3 || n.length == 7 || n.length == 13)){
    s="-";
}
```

Then, check if the key was backspace in your key handler:

```
function forceNumber(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 58) && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 188 && keyCode != 189) {
        return false;
    }
    // check if the key was backspace (key code 8)
    if (keyCode == 8) lastKeyIsBackspace = true;
    else lasyKeyIsBackspace = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `forceNumber` is triggered by `keypress`, backspace doesn't trigger `keypress`

Comment: @tckmn
Can you please help in my code. i have implemented your code. but may be i am doing some mistake. I am not able delete hyphen after adding it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-date-format-limit-customized-v3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. One thing I'm doing is removing the javascript from the actual dom elements. So your input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="input" size="25" style="text-align:right" />
```

UPDATE: since I noticed you have jquery sourced and you prefer the dashes to show before the 4th and 7th digits are typed. the following should be good for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/3e9XE/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#phone_number").on("keypress", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 58) && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 188 && keyCode != 189) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .on("keyup", function (e) {
        var str = this.value;
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            if ("-" == str.charAt(str.length - 1)) {
                str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
            }
        } else {
            str = str.replace(/\D/g, '')
                .replace(/(\d{3})(.*)/, "$1-$2")
                .replace(/(\d{3}-\d{3})(.*)/, "$1-$2");
        }
        this.value = str;
    });
});
```

Comment: Smerny - thank you.  It's working fantastically in fiddle but when I call the code in the php file it's not working in the same way.  Is there some difference I would need to make in utilizing this in a .js file that is called?  I tried this exact code (the first implementation) here: http://jannus.org/wp-login.php?action=register by calling a file phoneNumber.js created with what you'd suggested and called with code....

Comment: here is the code it was called with: `        $phone_number = ( isset( $_POST['phone_number'] ) ) ? $_POST['phone_number']: '';
        ?>
        <p id="phone_number">
            <label for="phone_number"><?php _e('Phone Number','mydomain') ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="input" size="25" style="text-align:right" />
        <?php` which for some reason is not implementing it(?)

Comment: I like the second and how the dash shows up before the digits!  It looks great, now I just need to see if I can get it implemented.  I'm going to try your suggestion a bit later this afternoon and see if I can get it going.  BTW do I need to change to position of that code to use that wrap?

Comment: I've just updated my answer based on these comments and that you are using jquery. Try that, also you should be able to copy and paste it into your `phoneNumber.js` file

Comment: Awesome.  Works great smerny.  Thank you for your awesomeness.  -Helena

Comment: Actually, smerny....I thought this was resolved but I am still unable to remove the dashes with a simple backspace.  You can still see it here:  jannus.org/wp-login.php?action=register.  If you type in a few numbers and get a dash and then hit backspace to delete it the dash reappears.  Not sure why this dang dash is so persistent.

Comment: It works. I don't see your issue. Also, just in general for best practice you should separate your logic from your dom.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure why it was still eating those dashes.  Thanks for the tip about the separation.  Cheers and thanks again.